# Ijson parse from list

Tags: python, json, ijson

I have a list in which each item contains JSON data, so I am trying to parse the data using [`Ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) since the data load will be huge.

[image: Image for the list]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
article_data=#variable which contains the list
parser = ijson.parse(article_data)
for id in ijson.items(parser, 'item'):
    if(id['article_type'] != "Monthly Briefing" and id['article_type']!="Conference"):
        data_article_id.append(id['article_id'])
        data_article_short_desc.append(id['short_desc'])
        data_article_long_desc.append(id['long_desc'])
```

This is the error I get:

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'read'

I thought of converting the `list` into `string` and then try to parse in `Ijson`, but it fails and gives me the same error.

Any suggestions please?

```
data_article_id=[] 
data_article_short_desc=[] 
data_article_long_desc=[] 

for index in article_data: 
    parser = ijson.parse(index)
    for id in ijson.items(parser, 'item'):
        if(id['article_type'] != "Monthly Briefing" and id['article_type']!="Conference"):
            data_article_id.append(id['article_id'])
            data_article_short_desc.append(id['short_desc'])
            data_article_long_desc.append(id['long_desc'])
```

since it is in list, i tried this one also .. but it is giving me the same error.

'generator' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Is each element in your list a json object? You may need to call parse on each one individually. I recommend removing lines from your code or stepping through it until you can find exactly the line giving you this error.

Comment: I assume `article_data` should be a File Handle instead of Type `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a list of byte string json object that you want to parse.

ijson.items(JSON, prefix) takes a readable byte object as input. That is it takes a opened file or file-like object as input. Specifically, the input should be bytes file-like objects.

If you are using Python 3, you can use `io` module with 
[io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) to create a in-memory binary stream.

#### Example

Suppose input is [b'{"id": "ab"}', b'{"id": "cd"}']

```
list_json = [b'{"id": "ab"}', b'{"id": "cd"}']
for json in list_json:
    item = ijson.items(io.BytesIO(json), "")
    for i in item:
        print(i['id'])
Output: 
    ab
    cd
```